# How to change the base color of an application

Tags: android, android-studio

When I launch my application, the screen goes white before displaying my Splash Screen

I would like to remove if possible or put the background the same color as my Splash Screen

But I do not know how, Can someone help me

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove your splash screen code as the white screen is itself a splash, provided by android. You just need to change it according to your need.

You first need to create a drawable with name `splash_screen.xml` and put this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/black"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</layer-list>
```

after that you need to create a activity which launches your `MainActivity`

Something like this

```
class OnBoardingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        DashboardActivity.launch(this)
        finish()
    }
}
```

then you need to overwrite the default splash screen with your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    </style>
```

after that last step is to add this theme in your manifest.
the activity which launches the app will have this style

```
   <activity
            android:name=".ui.onboarding.OnBoardingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use separate activity for your splash screen

**xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#dddddd"
tools:context=".SplashScreen">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_icon" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Splash Screen"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
```

**Class**

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            SplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            SplashScreen.this.finish();
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

}

**Manifest**
( Launch Activity as SplashActivity )

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashtoMain">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```